# I can't sort numbers in an array (tried everything that was written here, stil doesnt work)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting, object

I've been doing a little game in JS and I got to the point, when I have an array with 4 numbers (one of them is the correct result, the other 3 are random). I need to sort them (ascending) but nothing seems to work. I tried E6 and E2015 funcitons that are mentioned here but nothing. I¨M including my code plus code from the console so you would see. Do you know how to deal with it or where is the problem? Thank you for your time.

```
//this is the code i have:
   var rnum1 = generateRandomNumber1 ();
            var rnum2 = generateRandomNumber2 ();
            var rnums = [rnum1, rnum2];
            var rnumsSort = rnums.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
             var data= generateRandomOperatorAndCorrectResult(rnumsSort[0],rnumsSort[1]);
             //data=["+", [5]]
             var operator=data[0];
             var corResult = data[1][0][0];
             var ranResult =[data[1][0][1],data[1][0][2],data[1][0][3]];
             var allResults = data[1];
             var sortAllResults = allResults.sort(function(a,b){
    return a - b});
             var mes=alert(sortAllResults); 

//I'm sure all of my function are working because it alerts the actual 4 numbers in the array (var allResults = data[1]) but it doesnt do the sort method

 function generateRandomOperatorAndCorrectResult (num1, num2) {
        var operators = [{
            sign: "+",
            method: function(rnum1,rnum2){ return rnum1 + rnum2; } },
            {
             sign: "*",
             method: function(rnum1,rnum2){ return rnum1 * rnum2; } },
             {
             sign: "-",
            method: function(rnum1,rnum2){ return rnum1 - rnum2; }
              }];
        var results = [];

        var selectedOperator = Math.floor(Math.random()*operators.length);
        var randomOperator = operators[selectedOperator].sign;
        var correctResult = (operators[selectedOperator].method(num1, num2)); //pass the numbers to the methods
        results.push(correctResult);
        var randomResult = generateRandomResults(3);
        var result = results.concat(randomResult);
        return [randomOperator, [result]];

           }
```

Comment: I dont think `{return b-a}` sort in ascending order , also show the array which you wnat to sort

Comment: Does changing var allResults = data[1]; to var allResults = data[1][0]; do anything? Looks like there's an extra array in there?

Comment: explain the functions `generateRandomNumber1` and `generateRandomNumber2 `

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to sort an array of arrays. When you declare other variables, you're going like this:

```
data[1][0][0]
```

This means that `data` is an array, containing at least one array, which contains at least one array, which contains your data.

However, when you declare `allResults` (the array you want to sort), you set it one level up - you're setting it equal to an array containing an array, which contains your data. So you're actually sorting an array of arrays.

To fix this, simply declare `allResults` like so:

```
var allResults = data[1][0];
```

And then you will be comparing numbers, not arrays.

Comment: oh thank you, I haven't thought about that:-) It works now.